# Retrieve Product's Top Category from Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a Product in my Magento shop. It is in Category C.

My architecure is **Category A > Category B > Category C**.

With my code below, this displays Category B when on the Product page. How would I adapt the code below to display **Category A** instead?

```
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {

    $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $parentCategoryId = $_category->getParentId();
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);

    $url = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$parentCategory->name));

    echo '<a href="/'.$url.'">'.$parentCategory->name.'</a>';

}
```

I had thought of maybe using the number of '/' in the URL to change my code.

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Category C**'s parent category is **Category B**, not **Category A**. To get the *top-level* parent category for a given product, you need to climb up the category tree:

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');

while ($category->getLevel() != 2) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getParentId());
}
```

Each category has a level: level 1 is the catalog root, level 2 is a top-level category, and anything over level 2 is a subcategory.

Comment: Good God! I've literally spent all day tearing (what little hair I have) out over this and you nail it in 1 go. Please sir, have a virtual beer or refreshment of your choice on me. Thank You!!!